# Is there any API to change username of an user

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

Is there any API to change username of an registerd user. Ejabberd doesn't provide any type of api key to change username so, any way to do this? Maybe a new API written in PHP or ejabberdctl command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't such a thing. If you store the information in a SQL database, you can simply replace the username in the corresponding tables.